# Acess GitHub repository using ftp

Tags: github, ftp

Hello is there any way I can acess my **GitHub Repostiry** files using a **FTP** server

I want to make a image gallery site where I can upload images using a ftp connection

Comment: Why do you want to store those images in a git repo? Use something more suitable like a file store (e.g. S3).

Answer (score 0):

No, a git repository is not simply a directory of files, and thus, FTP is not a tool that can deal with that. You'll have to learn basic git usage.

Anyway, an image gallery site is definitely not the kind of thing you want to host as git repository somewhere; wrong approach.

Comment: You're welcome, but you don't have to thank me verbally. That's what upvote and accept buttons are for on this site! You don't have to upvote/accept, either, by the way, if something doesn't answer your question.